# what exactly are the four special oracle migration fields including integration_id

Tags: oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, informatica

Data is being transferred from Oracle OACS to SnowFlake. As a result, there are columns row_wid, etl_proc_wid, datasource_num_id, and integration_id. From looking at some documentation and some tables - I am left with the idea that this is something like.

`etl_proc_id` ... indicates a specific transfer (of a table?)

`datasource_num_id` ... says which source (?) the data was transferred from

`integration_id` ... indicates a specific transfer of a specific row

`row_wid` ... artificial primary key for the target table.

I am fairly sure I have not got this right.

But, what in a nutshell is the right idea here?

Comment: are you using informatica powercenter ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Not using Informatica PowerCenter directly, rather, I am accessing the tables in SnowFlake using SQL queries from Python. I am trying to understand exactly what these four columns are telling me.